# JavaScript works in IE, but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, firebug

Same old same old, my javascript runs fine in IE but not with Firefox.  I've followed all the forms, checked all the forums and responses, and what I've got coded up *should* work but it's not.  Firebug shows the value as "undefined."

Here's what I've got; it's scaled down from a much bigger application, but it shows the same problem:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_alert(evt)
{
if( !evt )
    evt = window.event;

var eSrc;
if( evt.srcElement )
    eSrc = evt.srcElement;
else
    eSrc = evt.target;

if( eSrc.tableisloaded == "showAlert" ) 
    alert("alert box: " + eSrc.name + "|" + eSrc.type);
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="clickme" tableisloaded="showAlert"
 onclick="show_alert(event);" value="Show alert box" />

 </body>
</html>
```

When I run this in IE, I get the alert, which means it is finding the "tableisloaded" argument.  Firebug doesn't show it all.

So what am I doing wrong, and is there a way to access the argument?  Will I need to change it to a parameter (`onclick="show_alert(event,"showAlert");`)?  I am hoping NOT as it will require a major rewrite of a LOT of code.

Thanks

Comment: "works in IE, but not Firefox" - Something is horribly wrong.

Comment: Its not that uncommon, imho. Getting one to work fine is easy, getting code that works fine in *both* is the tricky part.

Comment: getting things to work in most other browsers is easy, getting it to work for EACH version of IE is a PITA

Comment: jQuery is like a super-strength headache tablet that makes this pain go away.

Answer (score 11):

Try `eSrc.getAttribute("tableisloaded")`

Also, if you want to be hip and trendy, you might consider making your pages HTML5 and calling your extra attribute "data-tableIsloaded". That way it'll validate.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">    
<title>Added attributes</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function show_alert(evt){
    evt= window.event || evt;
    var eSrc= evt.srcElement || evt.target; 
    if(eSrc.getAttribute('data-tableisloaded')== "showAlert"){
        alert("alert box: " + eSrc.name + "|" + eSrc.type);
    }
}
onload=function(){
    document.getElementsByName('clickme')[0].onclick=show_alert;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" name="clickme" data-tableisloaded="showAlert" 
value="Show alert box" >

</body>
</html>
```

// pointy answered while I was still typing, and I gave him an upvote-
but this is what he said....